# Is there a way to split (bootstrap) carousel content in 1 slide into 2 carousel slides dynamically?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am currently rendering the carousel slides for Twitter Bootstrap's carousel using for-loops. For each slide, the content is dynamically inserted as well with a nested for-loop. What I want is to limit the number of items appearing in each slide (i.e. 2 items). If there are more, I would want to move them into the next slide.

So basically, for each 2 items in the inner for-loop, create a new carousel slide, but making sure it is part of the parent carousel (not a new carousel altogether).

Attached an image to hopefully illustrate my point better.

[image]

Code that I have so far (using PHP framework Laravel):

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @foreach ($carousel_slide) <!--rendering the carousel slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($inner_content) <!--rendering the items in each slide-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="inner-carousel-item">
                            {{{ $inner_content->image }}}
                        <span>{{{ $inner_content->caption }}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
         </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario is recommended to use regular for loop and keep incrementing the index.

In inner cycle add 2 items and increment the counter each time. Here is the meta code for this

```
for (;count($arr)>0;)
build next carousel page
for (;count($arr)>0;$item=array_pop($arr))
build item on carousel page
endfor
endfor
```

Comment: .. but that only addresses the inner loop but does not render another slide for me in the parent carousel.

Comment: That handles both of the loops. Outer loop does not increment and jsut checks if there are still items left in array. Inner loop increments the counter and takes items out of array.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confused. Isn't the outer loop the one that renders the carousel slides? <div class="item"> is the div for each slide. If i were to increment it in the inner cycle (this is correct), where does it 'say' to slot the extra items into a new <div class="item">?

Comment: I added a meta code example to help clarify the situation